# How to schedule a task in Java to hit a url and retrieve the response

Tags: java, url, scheduler

I have to **schedule** a task in Java to hit a specified url and get the response.

This url hit could be on a monthly basis. How could I implement this in Java? Please help!

Comment: Look at the Executor class in the concurrency package.

Comment: Is the application always running? Or do you want to trigger the start of a Java App?

Comment: As you want to return a response. you can use ExecutorService java.util.concurrent package which returns Future object

Comment: As @duffymo said, you can use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate() but I wouldn't keep a Java program running for a month (even if idle). I think you'd better write a plain old get routine in a standalone program and setup the program in Cron or Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: The application is always running but this program to hit a specified url should happen on a monthly basis .. could u pls share the sample code

Comment: @ Sergio ... I think you'd better write a plain old get routine in a standalone program and setup the program in Cron or Windows Task Scheduler.. could u pls share a sample code for implementing it in windows task scheduler.. am a newbie to this field

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer class and write a new class extending TimerTask. 
The TimerTask implementation will be called by a Timer.

You can ive the Timer a specific Date, when it should schedule the given Task.

```
timer.schedule( new Task(), new Date(2017,12,1);
```

The run() method if the Task() will now be called on the first of Dezmeber in 2017.

```
class Task extends TimerTask{
  private Date nextRun;
  public TimerTask(){
      nextRun = Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
  }

  @Override public void run(){
   //Do your URL stuff here
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule( new Task(), nextRun);
  }
}
```

It will create a Task for the current Date + 1 Month. When the Task runs, it will automatically create a new Task, which will run a Month later.

Comment: can u give a sample code to hit the specified url on a monthly basis

Comment: What do you mean with "hit a url"? I already gave you example code, how to do it monthly.

Comment: I have to hit another appln and retrieve the response

Comment: That is not a good question. I don't know, what you mean. Give a example. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
//Create a class extends TimerTask
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    Date date; 
    // Add your task here
    public void run() {
        // initialize date
        date = new Date(); 
        System.out.println("Time is :" + date);
    }
}

Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
time.schedule(st, 0, 1000); // Create Repetitively task for every 1 secs
```

You can adjust the time by changing the time in time.schedule method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the external Quartz Library for the same. Below is link for the same.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/quick-start.html

Comment: You don't need a Library for that. You can simply use the Java Timer and TimeTask classes. A Library would be a overload.

Comment: Yes why not you can do that. But if you want more features like stop the  task, reschedule task and etc you can use the quartz.

Comment: You are right, but it is better to keep it simple (at least in my opinion). And Quartz does much more, then he need.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Check the solution given by MkYong. Simply call this method with in run method().